# Convert rows into columns and group by specific column

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I could not find a suitable answer so I am writing it here. I have a table with following fields.

| Year | Month | Product | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | Jan-20 | A | 1500 |
| 2020 | Jan-25 | A | 2000 |
| 2021 | Jan-10 | A | 3000 |
| 2021 | Feb-15 | B | 2500 |

Excepted output

| 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | Jan |
| Jan | Feb |

Comment: Looks like a case for `pivot` - see https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation along with `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function such
as

```
WITH t1 AS
(
 SELECT Year, Month, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY Year 
             ORDER BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'yyyy-')||Month,'yyyy-Mon-dd')) AS rn
   FROM t
 GROUP BY Year, Month
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Year = 2020 THEN SUBSTR(Month,1,3) END) AS "2020",
       MAX(CASE WHEN Year = 2021 THEN SUBSTR(Month,1,3) END) AS "2021"      
  FROM t1
 GROUP BY rn
 ORDER BY rn
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CuiYXliP)</kbd>